# vue.js + gulp. How to build in a single js and css file.

Tags: gulp, webpack, vue.js, browserify

i have a  [gulpfile.js](https://github.com/versh23/gulp-boilerplate/blob/master/gulpfile.js)

i cant understand, how i can merge app.js and bundle.js together. app.css and bundle.css together too

How i can start "scripts" and "styles" tasks after "vue" task?

May be a better way use only webpack, without gulp ?

Comment: Checkout my project on GitHub and see how I use Gulp with Webpack and VueJS https://github.com/bedakb/vuewp

Answer (score 0):

run-sequence solve my problem.

```
gulp.task('build-vue', function(callback) {
   runSequence('clean', 'vue', ['styles', 'scripts'], ['clean-vue', 'fonts'] , callback);
```

});